# JDOM XML Element add Element

Tags: xml, jdom

unfortunately I need your help again.

Exactly my Problem is that I'm not able to add an

```
Element rootElement
```

to an exact position in an other

`Element el`.

For Example

```
<Person>
         <Name>Hansi</Name>
         <Child name = "Susi">
                  <Child name = "Max">
                           <Age>13</Age>
                  </Child >
                  <Child name="Mimmi">
                           <Age>3</Age>
                  </Child >
         </Child >
</Person>
```

Now I want to add this Element a new Element (a child).

```
<Child name = "Max">
         <Age>13</Age>
</Child >
```

So I searched the Element where name = "Max", but I don't know how I can add this Element a new Element, so that the root Element contains it too.

```
//filter = "Child"
Element addElement;
ElementFilter filter = new org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter(element.getName());
            for (Element c : rootElementOutput.getDescendants(filter)) {
                if (c.getAttributeValue("name").equals(element.getAttributeValue("name"))) {
                    addElement = c;
                    // so funktioniert es leider nicht!!
                    //c.getChildren().add(aktNodeOutput);
                }
            }
```

Here the imports I use:

```
Java Code:  Quelltext in neuem Fenster öffnen
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter;
```

I hope you know what I mean and I explained it more or less well.

Thank you in advance for your help

Best regards,

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a completely new Element with the exact same properties, and then remove the old one from the root.

So go through the loop, find the correct Element (The one called "Max") and add all of its properties to a new Element plus the Element you want as its child.
Then remove the old "Max" and add the new "Max" to the root.

There is a method called clone() for Elements which makes it easier to make a new Element without having to copy everything manually.

Hopefully I've helped a bit :)